# How to pass schema to create a new Dataframe from existing Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

To pass schema to a json file we do this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import (StructField, StringType, StructType, IntegerType)
data_schema = [StructField('age', IntegerType(), True), StructField('name', StringType(), True)]
final_struc = StructType(fields = data_schema)
df =spark.read.json('people.json', schema=final_struc)
```

The above code works as expected. However now, I have data in table which I display by:

```
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM people_json")
```

But if I try to pass a new schema to it by using following command it does not work.

```
df2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people_json", schema=final_struc)
```

It gives the following error:

> sql() got an unexpected keyword argument 'schema'

NOTE: I am using [Databrics Community Edition](https://community.cloud.databricks.com/)

- What am I missing?
- How do I pass the new schema if I have data in the table instead of some JSON file?

Comment: doesn't sql() takes only one parameter as the string?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Yes. That is the issue I'm trying to figure a way out of. My question is how do I pass the new schema if I have data in the table instead of some `json file`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot apply a new schema to already created dataframe. However, you can change the schema of each column by casting to another datatype as below.

```
df.withColumn("column_name", $"column_name".cast("new_datatype"))
```

If you need to apply a new schema, you need to convert to RDD and create a new dataframe again as below

```
df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM people_json")
val newDF = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema=schema)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, doing `newDF = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, data_schema)` gives `AttributeError: 'StructField' object has no attribute 'encode'` **Error**

Comment: I passed `final_struc` instead of `data_schema` in `spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, schema=final_struc)`

Comment: Thank you! I was using createDataFrame(df,collect(), schema=schema) and it was very slow and memory ineficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is already one answer available but still I want to add something.

1. Create DF from RDD

- using toDF

  newDf = rdd.toDF(schema, column_name_list)
- using createDataFrame

  newDF = spark.createDataFrame(rdd ,schema, [list_of_column_name])

2. Create DF from other DF

suppose I have DataFrame with columns|data type - name|string, marks|string, gender|string.

if I want to get only marks as integer.

```
newDF = oldDF.select("marks")
newDF_with_int = newDF.withColumn("marks", df['marks'].cast('Integer'))
```

This will convert marks to integer.