# Writing null values to Parquet in Spark when the NullType is inside a StructType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm importing a collection from MongodB to Spark. All the documents have field 'data' which in turn is a structure and has field 'configurationName' (which is always null).

```
val partitionDF = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("database", "db").option("collection", collectionName).load()
```

For the `data` column in the resulting `DataFrame`, I get this type:

```
StructType(StructField(configurationName,NullType,true), ...
```

When I try to save the dataframe as Parquet

```
partitionDF.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(collectionName + ".parquet")
```

I get the following error:

AnalysisException: Parquet data source does not support struct<configurationName:null, ...

It looks like the problem is that I have that `NullType` buried in the `data` column's type. I'm looking at [How to handle null values when writing to parquet from Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160682/how-to-handle-null-values-when-writing-to-parquet-from-spark) , but it only shows how to solve this `NullType` problem on the top-level columns.

But how do you solve this problem when a `NullType` is not at the top level? The only idea I have so far is to flatten the dataframe completely (exploding arrays and so on) and then all the `NullType`s would pop at the top. But in such a case I would lose the original structure of the data (which I don't want to lose).

Is there a better solution?

Comment: new schema with "NullType" replaced with appropriate type can be created, with recursion, and then assigned via RDD:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739752/how-to-pass-schema-to-create-a-new-dataframe-from-existing-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Building on [How to handle null values when writing to parquet from Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50160682/how-to-handle-null-values-when-writing-to-parquet-from-spark) and [How to pass schema to create a new Dataframe from existing Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739752/how-to-pass-schema-to-create-a-new-dataframe-from-existing-dataframe) (the second is suggested by @pasha701, thanks!), I constructed this:

```
def denullifyStruct(struct: StructType): StructType = {
  val items = struct.map{ field => StructField(field.name, denullify(field.dataType), field.nullable, field.metadata) }
  StructType(items)
}

def denullify(dt: DataType): DataType = {
  dt match {
    case struct: StructType => denullifyStruct(struct)
    case array: ArrayType => ArrayType(denullify(array.elementType), array.containsNull)
    case _: NullType => StringType
    case _ => dt
  }
}
```

which effectively replaces all `NullType` instances with `StringType` ones.

And then

```
val fixedDF = spark.createDataFrame(partitionDF.rdd, denullifyStruct(partitionDF.schema))
fixedDF.printSchema
```

Answer (score 1):

@Roman Puchkovskiy : Rewritten your function using pattern matching.

```
  def deNullifyStruct(struct: StructType): StructType = {
    val items = struct.map { field => StructField(field.name, fixNullType(field.dataType), field.nullable, field.metadata) }
    StructType(items)
  }
  def fixNullType(dt: DataType): DataType = {
    dt match {
      case _: StructType => return deNullifyStruct(dt.asInstanceOf[StructType])
      case _: ArrayType =>
        val array = dt.asInstanceOf[ArrayType]
        return ArrayType(fixNullType(array.elementType), array.containsNull)
      case _: NullType => return StringType
      case _ => return dt
    }
  }
```

Comment: Oh, I was going to do it myself a bit later. Thanks! :)